# How to get files and their corresponding ID

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi guys i've been thinking about the best to do this but am coming short, am hoping someone can help me out.
Here's what am trying to achieve: So i wanna display all the folders in myDrive with their ID in a button, but have the ID hidden. So when i click on a folder i can copy all the folders and files within it using the getFolderByID method.
I hope y'all understand what am trying to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get Id of all the folders in your drive owned by you -

```
function getFolderIDs() {
    var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('"me" in owners');  *// get all the folders with you as owner*
    var foldArr = [];  *//Declare an array*

    while(folders.hasNext()) {   *//Keep looping till the folders are there*
        var folderId = folders.next().getId();  *// Get Id of each folder*
        foldArr.push(folderId);    *//Capture the IDs in the array*
    }

    Logger.log(foldArr)    *//foldArr will contain ID of the all the folders*
}
```